# Can I add specificity to a kwarg in a subclass' constructor?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, python-typing

I am trying to get PyCharm to understand that the subclass of my base controller class only takes a specific type of widget.

Minimal example:

```py
import tkinter as tk


class BaseWidgetController:
    def __init__(self, parent: 'tk.Widget'): # Parent is always __some__ kind of widget
        self._parent = parent


class EntryWidgetController(BaseWidgetController):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self._parent: 'tk.Entry' # On this class, I want Pycharm to understand _parent is only ever an Entry (a subclass of tk.Widget), but even adding this line doesn't change its mind.

    def say_type(self) -> None:
        print(type(self._parent)) # PyCharm still thinks _parent is a tk.Widget


ew = EntryWidgetController(parent=tk.Frame())
ew.say_type()  # Obviously this works fine at runtime.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to constrain the *EntryWidgetController* so that it only accepts `tk.Entry` or subclasses, the fix is rather simple - just do

```
class EntryWidgetController(BaseWidgetController):
    def __init__(self, parent: 'tk.Entry', **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent=parent, **kwargs)
```

That way

```
ew = EntryWidgetController(parent=tk.Frame())
```

will make PyCharm complain that `Expected type 'Entry', got 'Frame' instead`.